# Xcode iOS app with multiple GUIs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

I am developing an app where I am not sure which interface suits my users best. So I want to provide them multiple GUIs which they can choose in the settings.

What would be the best way to implement multiple interfaces? Can I just add another storyboard and then switch between them somehow?

Comment: Two tips: 1) search before asking - a quick google for `swift multiple storyboards` would give you all the info you need. 2) see tip #1

Comment: This is why we have MVC, Only thing you need is to modify V (View) . You should not change the ViewController , rather just the view programmatically & storyboard mix. And that what happens when you actually rotate your device  (View redraws itself)

Comment: But how can I switch the Storyboard when the user selects another GUI?

Comment: @ITStudent - start by learning how to load View Controllers from different Storyboards... then start designing your GUI(s)... then put it together.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do what you're thinking of doing. You can either do multiple storyboards or just have different viewController in your one storyboard and instantiate them in times when you need them.